# How to deploy a WCF Workflow Service Application on Windows 7 / IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, windows-7, c#-4.0, wcf

I've got a WCF Workflow Service Application in .NET 4.0, and usually we deploy to Windows Server 2008.

For that I create a Deployment Package in VS 2010 which creates a .zip.  The I open IIS 7 select the site and right click to select Deploy | Import.

However, for development purposes I want to run this on my desktop.  I can't see how to deply the zip to IIS 7 in Windows 7.  I created a site but I don't get a Deploy option on right click.

How should I deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have IIS Web Deploy installed on your local machine?  If not, install it, and you should have the same deploy menu you get on your servers.

http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy

Your other option is to manually deploy (not using the deploy snap in). I forgot the exact msdeploy .zip package format, but you should be able to get the app files out of the zip and extract to whatever location you are using for the site's root.

Answer (score 6):

By default, IIS 7.0 is not configured for WCF services. Here are the steps to configure IIS 7.0 to run WCF services:

**INSTALLING IIS ADDONS**

Go to Control Panel –> Programs –> Turn windows feature on or off. Wait for a list to compile here in Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 or higher section check both "Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation" and "Window Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation" addons. In section Internet Information Services check all the addons under "Web Management Tools" this is to directly publish WCF from Visual Studio. Press OK and the installation will complete.

**ADD MIME TYPE**

At the IIS control panel  double click on the MIME Types applet. On the Actions menu, click on the Add menu item. A window pops up, enter the following information:

> File name extension: .svc
>
> MIME type:  application/octet-stream

**ADD HANDLER MAPPING**

Click again on the Default Web Site node on the left side, then double click on the Handler Mappings applet icon on the right side. On the Actions menu, click on the Add Managed Handler. A window pops up, enter the following information:

> Request path: *.svc
>
> Type: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler
>
> Name: svc-Integrated

IIS is configured for WCF service now we have to deploy a service.

Deploy your service via Visual Studio as Administrator. Right click on Service project file and click to Publish, Now in newly opened dialogue box select Default Application and click the button Create New Web Application name it accordingly and click Open.